# I tried to retrieve data from database using Ajax but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I saw a lot of youtube videos and article and I come out with this code but unfortunately, it does not even go inside script I tried to put an alert inside the script to check but nothing shows up
in the same page I have three input text ( item name and Offer pc and price after discount)
and I try to let the ajax work with these inputs and do some calculations if the user put the Offer pc first directly will calculate the price after discount and if the user put Offer pc first directly will calculate the price after discount

already I download the jquery library and put it in the same direction

this is the script inside div in the manageOffer page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var iname=document.getElementById("iname").value;
     var pname=$login_session;
     alert("Hello");//this for check but its not shows up at all
     $(document).ready(function() { 
         setInterval(function(){ 
         if(iname != "" || iname!=null){
         var price;
         //=load("SOPC.php",{
             //name: iname,
            // phname : pname
         //});
         $.ajax({
            url: 'SOPC.php',
            method: 'POST',
             dataType: 'html',
           data: {name: iname ,  phname : pname},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                price = data.d.responseText;
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex.responseText);
            }
        });


         var pc=document.getElementById("pc").value;
         var ap=document.getElementById("price").value;
         if(pc!= "" || pc!=null){
            ap.value=((pc/100.0)*price); 
         }
         else if(ap!= "" || ap!=null){
             pc.value=(ap*price*100);

         }
         }   
     },3000);
     });

 </script>
```

and this    SOPC.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pname=$_POST['phname'];

  $sql="SELECT ItemInBranch.Price from ItemInBranch INNER JOIN Item         ON ItemInBranch.ItemNo= Item.ItemNo  AND Item.ItemName='$name' INNER     JOIN Branch  ON ItemInBranch.branchNo= Branch.branchNo  AND    Branch.pharmacyID='$pname'  ";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   if( $result){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
   echo $row['Price'];
  }


 }



 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding wrong condition:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   if( !$result){ // => This should be if ($result){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
   echo $row['Price'];
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much for that but still doesn't retrieve anything  and the code doesn't work

Comment: Please print your SQL and run in PhpMyAdmin or any other MySQL tool you have available.

Comment: yes I try it in Myphp before I write the PHP file and its work

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'SOPC.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{name: iname ,  phname : pname},//You missed ':' here
                success: function (data) {
                  alert(data)//For testing
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(ex.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you very much for your notice but still doesn't retrieve anything and the code doesn't work

Comment: in sopc.php <?php 
echo "1" 
 ?>

Comment: It does not work, actually I am still beginner in coding but all the ajax examples i saw work after click button or something is that problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You checked wrong condition in SOPC.php
Try below one

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pname=$_POST['phname'];

  $sql="SELECT ItemInBranch.Price from ItemInBranch INNER JOIN Item ON ItemInBranch.ItemNo= Item.ItemNo  AND Item.ItemName='$name' INNER     JOIN Branch  ON ItemInBranch.branchNo= Branch.branchNo  AND    Branch.pharmacyID='$pname'  ";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   if($result){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
       echo $row['Price'];
    } else {
      //something here
    }

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: I fixed that by removing "!" but still not work actually it doesn't go inside script at all and doesn't call SOPC.php

Comment: give total url:"full file path" instead of giving  url: 'SOPC.php'

Answer (score 0):

in ajax script menson response => dataType: 'html'

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'SOPC.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html', //here 
                data:{name: iname ,  phname : pname},
                success: function (data) {
                  alert(data)//For testing
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(ex.responseText);
                }
            });
```

also change condition in SOPC.php

```
if($result){ //change here
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
       echo $row['Price'];
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: I fixed that by removing "!" but still not work actually it doesn't go inside script at all and doesn't call SOPC.php and I add alert to check but it doesn't go inside first script and I don't know why

Comment: on page load this script is loaded?

Comment: check alert after this condition if(iname != "" || iname!=null){  alert('hi');}

Comment: so acjectly we know ajax loded or not

Comment: I update the code above I put the alert first thing in the script

Comment: refresh the page and check alert msg display or not

Comment: if not than check those condition and fix it